# Counting number of characters in a file through shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I want to check the no of characters in a file from starting to EOF character. Can anyone tell me how to do this through shell script

Answer (score 146, accepted):

This will do it for counting **bytes** in file:

```
wc -c filename
```

If you want only the count without the filename being repeated in the output:

```
wc -c < filename
```

This will count **characters** in multibyte files (Unicode etc.):

```
wc -m filename
```

(as shown in Sébastien's answer).

Comment: [Sébastien](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026214/counting-no-of-characters-in-a-file-through-shell-script/5026237#5026237)'s answer on multibyte files is an important point.

Comment: If I want to find count of specific word,without opening file,then ?

Comment: @SagarNikam: You should ask that as a new question. It can't be done without opening the file, by the way, but I suppose you mean without using a file editor rather than without a program performing an `open()`. One way to do what you want would be along the lines of `grep -o '\<word\>' file | wc -l`

Comment: if I have a file with text 'david', that is 5 characters.  When I run wc -m or wc -c it outputs 6.  To get correct count, use printf 'David' | wc -m (or -c)

Comment: @OB7: As you're no doubt aware, the other character that's being counted in the file is the newline at the end of the line.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: I was not aware, but thanks to you, now I am. Thank you.

Comment: what about number of characters per line

Comment: @Amir: `awk '{print length}' filename` -
 based on a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8786674/26428)

Answer (score 25):

```
#!/bin/sh

wc -m $1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

`wc -m` counts the number of characters; the `awk` command prints the number of characters only, omitting the filename.

`wc -c` would give you the number of bytes (which can be different to the number of characters, as depending on the encoding you may have a character encoded on several bytes).

Comment: Having wc read from stdin instead of a file (`wc -m < "$1"`) means you don't have to pipe the output through awk to remove the filename.

Comment: awk may not be installed. Using `cut -f1 -d' '` instead is more portable.

Answer (score 7):

To get exact character count of string, use printf, as opposed to echo, cat, or running wc -c directly on a file, because using echo, cat, etc will count a newline character, which will give you the amount of characters including the newline character. So a file with the text 'hello' will print 6 if you use echo etc, but if you use printf it will return the exact 5, because theres no newline element to count.

How to use printf for counting characters within strings:

```
$printf '6chars' | wc -m
6
```

To turn this into a script you can run on a text file to count characters, save the following in a file called print-character-amount.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
characters=$(cat "$1")
printf "$characters" | wc -m
```

chmod +x on file print-character-amount.sh containing above text, place the file in your PATH (i.e. /usr/bin/ or any directory exported as PATH in your .bashrc file) then to run script on text file type:

```
print-character-amount.sh file-to-count-characters-of.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '{t+=length($0)}END{print t}' file3
```

Comment: +1 this will take care of encoded chars, good if you pay translations on a char basis :)

Answer (score 1):

awk only

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)c++}END{print "total chars:"c}' file
```

shell only

```
var=$(<file)
echo ${#var}
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -0777 -ne 'print $_.size' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script is tested and gives exactly the results, that are expected

```
\#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the file name"

read file

echo "enter the word to be found"

read word

count=0

for i in \`cat $file`

do

if [ $i == $word ]

then

count=\`expr $count + 1`

fi

done

echo "The number of words are $count"
```

Comment: hmm .. tried to format the code - but failed ;-) Please improve.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that it would be better to use `stat` to find the size of a file, since the filesystem knows it already, rather than causing the whole file to have to be read with `awk` or `wc` - especially if it is a multi-GB file or one  that may be non-resident in the file-system on an HSM.

```
stat -c%s file
```

Yes, I concede it doesn't account for multi-byte characters, but would add that the OP has never clarified whether that is/was an issue.

Comment: In my mind, you don't have to excuse yourself for adding to the answers. Both `stat` and `wc` spent 0.001s to tell me the number of bytes in a 1Gb file, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to user.py et al.

---

```
echo "ää" > /tmp/your_file.txt
cat /tmp/your_file.txt | wc -m
```

results in `3`.

In my example the result is expected to be `2` (twice the letter `ä`). However, echo (or vi) adds a line break `\n` to the end of the output (or file). So two `ä` and one Linux line break `\n` are counted. That's three together.

Working with pipes `|` is not the shortest variant, but so I have to know less `wc` parameters by heart. In addition, `cat` is bullet-proof in my experience.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver).