# bash script : Count max characters in line across text files that match filter

Tags: linux, bash, text

Want a linux/ unix script that will tell me max characters in any line in a directory tree.

So I can specify a root folder. It walks down it and processes files with some mask (like `*.java`) - a find command ... and then keeps the max characters in a line in a var and prints that.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786634/how-to-print-the-number-of-characters-in-each-line-of-a-text-file%20character%20count%20in%20all%20lines) but i wanted the maximum only without having to copy to spread sheet or other processing.

Dont want specific characters want to consider all characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that `find` command:

```
find -type f -iname "*.java" -exec awk 'length($0)>a{a=length($0)} END{print FILENAME":"a}' {} \;
```

**Explanation:**

- `-type f` fond only files
- `-iname "*.java"` only file ending with `.java`
- `-exec awk` execute `awk` for each file

  - `length($0)>a{a=length($0)}` if the length of the line is greater than `a` set `a` to that length.
  - `END{print FILENAME":"a}`: at the end, print the filename and the length

Answer (score 1):

This return the line with the most number of characters ( to count them pipe to wc -c ) in all *java files in the current directory:

```
perl -e 'while(<>){$l=length;  $l>$m && do {$c=$_; $m=$l}  } print $c' *.java
```

It's not exactly what you ask, but is a good starting point.